# Back link report

Tags: backlinks

Is there an application or site that can generate a back link report for a give web page?

The sort of information I'd like to see in this report, for each back link, would be:

1. Page's Title
2. Page's PageRank
3. Page's URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SEOmoz's [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/) will provide a backlink report which includes linking pages' titles and URL's for the top 1000 linking pages.

Google's own Webmaster Tools includes a [Links To Your Site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=55281) tool which includes backlink URL's for a nearly-comprehensive list of the linking pages which factor in to your site's ranking (note that nofollow links will not appear in this report) - you have the option to download the report's results as a CSV file if you want to spider linking pages to retrieve title information.

Google PageRank is not factored in with any of the services I am familiar with, though you have the option to research that on your own (keep in mind that you will never be presented with the effective PageRank ... [unless/until you're working for Google](http://groups.google.com/group/google_webmaster_help-indexing/browse_thread/thread/77e0c49987b66913?fwc=1&pli=1)).